# Has_Many Simple Form Nested Objects Form Form Not Posting User Values One Model has authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, simple-form, has-many

I am pretty sure my problem is a bit more complicated than the has_many nested forms questions that I have seen on stackoverflow

I have two models, one is company.rb and the other one is job.rb

the company.rb

```
has_many :jobs
accepts_nested_attributes_for :jobs, allow_destroy: true
attr_accessible :jobs_attributes
```

the job.rb has this

```
belongs_to :company
```

in my companies controller I have this

```
def new 
    @company = current_company.jobs.new
  end

  def create
    #the actual create process where the params from the forms got sent here
    @company = current_company.jobs.new(params[:company])
  end
```

I have devise for company under authentication so I want to create job for the currently logged in company

this is my form

```
<%= simple_form_for @company do |f| %>
    <%= f.input  :title %>
    <%= f.input  :description %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

every entry of job is getting created but the values are not passed into it? I am having empty job recorded with no company_id in the record as well.

I have been working on this for two days can somebody help me out? I tried fields_for on the form, but nothing is getting posted?

this is in my log

```
Processing by JobsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"9P+tEDamlP9+jEHU31gL93hc4GyhXTZoe3zoMopKHa0=", "job"=>{"title"=>"software", "description"=>"make software"}, "commit"=>"Create Job"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating the job not the company, so you need to use `params[:job]`.

Change the line in create action to:

```
@company = current_company.jobs.new(params[:job])
```

And it would be good if you use @job variable name as it will be more descriptive.

Comment: yes it works since this is a job object I moved it to the job controller and I also changed it to `@job` thank you very much